# How to remove previously set jQuery .wrapInner()?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#main').wrapInner('<div></div>')
```

`.wrap()` you just remove with `.unwrap()`

`.unwrapInner()` seems to be not in the library.

`.unwrap()` not working with `.wrapInner()`

Somebody faced the same problem? Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you can put a marker class on your `div` elements (it probably won't matter, but just in case):

```
$("#main").wrapInner('<div class="wrapper"></div>'); // Notice class=wrapper
```

Then you can unwrap it using `contents().unwrap()`:

```
$("#main > .wrapper").contents().unwrap();
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/wkvyzre6/

Comment: This helped me a lot using [bootstrap 4 border](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/) a label on [mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/). And also this [link](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/)